# How to overcome *-expansion in this command?

Tags: bash, unix, bc

I am trying to write a very simple script using bc.

My script is saved as `cl` and contains

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$@" | bc
```

But running `cl 2 * 3` gives several `(standard_in) 1: syntax error` lines.
Running `cl 2*3` gives correct output.

I believe * is expanding to filenames due to soft quotaion. How to avoid it ?

Comment: Quoting is the answer!

Answer (score 1):

As always, quote or escape it.

```
cl 2 '*' 3
cl 2 \* 3
```